# Help installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 DVD in Windows 8

Tags: wubi, 64-bit, windows-8, dvd

I downloaded the 12.04.2 Desktop amd64 ISO from the main website. Then I burned it onto a DVD, but when I restart, the computer won't recognize the DVD when it boots.

[  [image: Image of the ISO]  ]

[image: Image of the contents of the burned DVD.]

Have I downloaded the wrong one as there is Wubi on the DVD?

Comment: Which Ubuntu were trying to download?  How are you trying to install?

Comment: "Files Ready to Be Written To the Disc"? Looks like something got wrong while burning. It can also be due to 'Secure Boot' blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right ISO. There is a `wubi.exe` on it (just ignore it - it has other uses other than just installing inside Windows).

There are two potential issues:

1. A bad ISO that was corrupted on download
2. A bad burn

To check the ISO, refer to this: [help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)
To prevent a bad burn, use the slowest possible speed and refer to this: [www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go into the PC Settings located on the bottom of the right side menu pop-up in Windows 8 and turn on the boot from DVD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with the boot mode. A UEFI boot won't recognize a Legacy DVD, so if your Windows 8 is installed in the UEFI mode, and your DVD is Legacy, then you need to change the boot mode from your boot options, else get a UEFI supported version.

Comment: Where Can i get a UEFI supported version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Here, check this out:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI .
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a usb?

you can create a bootable usb with this software:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/